# JAVA Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) on first DST day

Tags: java, calendar, dst

I'm having a problem with `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);`.
If I use the first DST day this method returns the previous day 23:00:00 instead of present day 00:00:00.

My timezone is **Brazil/East**

My code:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
Date day = getFirstDayDST();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( day );
System.out.println( sdt.format( cal.getTime() ) );
cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
System.out.println( sdt.format( cal.getTime() ) );
```

the output:

> ```
> "18/10/2015 12:00:00 PM GMT-02:00"
> "17/10/2015 11:00:00 PM GMT-03:00"
> ```

But I expected:

> ```
> "18/10/2015 12:00:00 PM GMT-02:00"
> "18/10/2015 00:00:00 PM GMT-02:00" OR "18/10/2015 01:00:00 PM GMT-02:00"
> ```

How I fix this problem?

Comment: just a representation, it means that returns the first day of Daylight Saving Time

Comment: What happens if you change your date format string to print the timezone, e.g., "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"? It won't fix the problem, but it might provide a clue.

Comment: @gFontaniva I tried your getFirstDayDST = new Date(1445176800000L), and got: 18/10/2015 12:00:00 -0200
18/10/2015 01:00:00 -0200; I don't know how you are getting "18/10/2015 12:00:00"
"17/10/2015 23:00:00". And one more thing - why your expectation is "18/10/2015 00:00:00", as it never happens I mean the clocks are set 1h forward at 00:00. See:http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia

Comment: @gFontaniva please put the code for the `getFirstDayDST()`, it seems relevant.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is that you printing "day.getTime()". You have to print cal.getTime() ;)

Comment: my mistake, I post the question whit error, but in code is 'cal'